# SwiftUI change the back button's color in NavigationLink

Tags: swiftui

In my SwiftUI code, I have a tabbed view and inside tab view I have the following code:

```
          NavigationView{
            VStack{
                 Form{
                     Section(){
                         NavigationLink(destination: Text("Second View")) {
                             Text("Elaqe")
                         }
                      } // section
                 } //form
             }
             .modifier(NavBarModifier(font: self.fontUI,text: "Support"))
         }
         .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

When I click on the Nav link, I get the following:

[image]

it's barely readable and I would want to change it's color. How can I do this?

Edit 1: Apparently the back button's color depends on tabView's `accentColor`. Is it possible to keep the accent color of tabbed view orange and change the back button's  color to something else?

Edit 2: Nav bar Modifier

```
func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content
        .zIndex(0)
        .animation(.spring())
        .padding(.top,80)
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(self.text),displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarHidden(false)
        .foregroundColor(.orange)
        .background(NavigationConfigurator { nc in
                       nc.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 243/255, green: 107/255, blue: 21/255, alpha: 1)
                       nc.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
                        .foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
                        .font : self.font,
                        .kern: 1.2
                       ]
        }
        .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing]))
    }
```

Comment: Would you show NavBarModifier?

Comment: @Asperi I added it to the question. However, I found out it is related to tab view's accent color rather than navbarmodifier.

Comment: On Xcode 12b3 / iOS 14 the `< Support` is blue, just in case.

Comment: thanks for this "Apparently the back button's color depends on tabView's accentColor" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to change `NavigationView` accentColor.

Comment: Good for you! Just be aware that it changes color not only for back button but for all default active elements inside NavigationView (buttons, bar items, etc).